# Android Listview item UI change

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview, each item in listview have a button.
I set a onClickListener to the button to play music.
Each time, only "ONE MUSIC" can be played!!!
But so far, I haven't implemented the play music part, I just handle the UI change first.
When I click the button,
1) The "play" image of the button will change to "stop".
2) If the music is already playing, it will stop the previous song(and change the UI of corresponding listview item image to "stop"), and then play the selected song(and change the UI of corresponding listview item image to "play).
Now I faced some problems and don't know how to fix it.
Q1) When one song is playing, and I scroll the listview up and down, the "stop" image will change back to "play", so the user don't know which item is playing.
Q2) This is the hardest problem!!
When one song is already playing, and user click another song, I don't know how to notify the previous listview item to change the UI from "song" to "play"(since the previous music will stop).

Comment: show how you implement `getView` method of your apdapter

Comment: A2: make a data structure for your songs and handle it in getview method, each song would have a flag ("play" | "not_play") and then depending on this flag stop or play the song at that index. You will need to have some sort of service that will ensure that one song is playing at a time (or maybe the player implementation should take care of that, because probably it wont allow two songs to play at the same time)

Comment: so that in the getView(), it will generate the list item again base on the boolean?

Comment: you specify (based on boolean) how to render your views and then you tell the adapter to redraw the views by using `notifyDataSetChanged()`